# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transaction' of undefined, library of contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, indexeddb

I have the next problem. I am trying to connect to my indexeddb and suddenly now I am happening to have the next error, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transaction' of undefined`.
What I want to do basically is extract the info that I already had saved into my `objectStore` and therefore display it to my screen throughout a carousel of pictures.
My code goes like this:

```
const DB_NAME = 'peliculas';
const DB_VERSION = 1; // No usar un floating
const DB_STORE_NAME = 'videos';
var db;

function openDb() {
    var req = indexedDB.open(DB_NAME, DB_VERSION);
    req.onsuccess = function (evt) {
      // Igual: db = req.result;
      db = this.result;
    };

    req.onerror = function (evt) {
      console.error("openDb:", evt.target.errorCode);
    };

    req.onupgradeneeded = function (evt) {
      var store = evt.currentTarget.result.createObjectStore(
        DB_STORE_NAME, { keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true });
      store.createIndex('id', 'id', { unique: true });
      store.createIndex('titulo', 'titulo', { unique: false });
      store.createIndex('anyo', 'anyo', { unique: false });
      store.createIndex('director', 'director', { unique: false });
      store.createIndex('sinopsis', 'sinopsis', { unique: false });
      store.createIndex('img', 'img', { unique: false });
    };
}


  /**
   * @param {string} store_name
   * @param {string} mode o "readonly" o "readwrite"
   */

function getObjectStore(store_name, mode) {
    var tx = db.transaction(store_name, mode);
    return tx.objectStore(store_name);
}

function clearObjectStore() {
    var store = getObjectStore(DB_STORE_NAME, 'readwrite');
    var req = store.clear();

    req.onsuccess = function(evt) {

        displayActionSuccess("Store cleared");
        displayMovieList(store);
    };
    req.onerror = function (evt) {
        console.error("clearObjectStore:", evt.target.errorCode);
        displayActionFailure(this.error);
    };
}
```

When I refresh with Cntrl + F5, the problem stops to persist at times, though at last tries while I was trying to experiment putting the variable  `var db` into different scopes, problem still remains unsolved.

It would be nice if someone could give me a hint on how-to tackle this error because I am starting to think that I am already at a dead-end. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `db` is `undefined` in `db.transaction(store_name, mode);`

Comment: @VLAZ And the reason is the `db = this.result` part arrives asynchronously.

Comment: And what is a possible approach of solving this ? I tried numerous things, tried moving the db variable to different scopes but I am not really understanding the part that arrives asynchronously to be sincere. The thing is that sometimes surely it does load but there are times that it won't load anything and the same error occurs.

Comment: Have you learned about how to use a callback function or work with promises? Now would be a good time to do so.

Comment: @Josh Well, I think I will have to try solving this with a callback function or promise as you said. Thanks!